# How is that a profit or a loss?

Tags: foreign-exchange

An investor enters into a short forward contract to sell 100,000 British pounds for US
dollars at an exchange rate of 1.4000 US dollars per pound. How much does the
investor gain or lose if the exchange rate at the end of the contract is (a) 1.3900 and
(b) 1.4200?

I can't figure why the investor has profit or loss? Let's say he bought 100,000 British pounds for US dollars at an exchange rate of 1.4000 US dollars, now he is selling at the same exchange rate, so he has no profit and loss. Why does the current exchange rate have anything to do with profit and loss? After all,
profit is net gain of money right?

Comment: Go back to your textbook and read the definition of "short forward contract".

Comment: Isn't it that he took short position in a forward contract?

Comment: Yep. Now think what this means to the payout.

Comment: Oh I got it, the investor doesn't need to own 100,000 British pounds , he can buy right at the moment and sell which determines the profit or loss. Thank you .

Comment: He will gain if the exchange rate is 1.39 or he loses if the exchange rate is 1.42

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a short contract. That means the seller sold 100,000 British Pound but he doesn’t actually have any. So at the end of the contract he has to buy 100,000 pound at the current exchange rate. Not at the exchange rate at the time of the contract. He has 140,000 dollars. At 1.3900 he has to pay $139,000 and has $1,000 left in his pocket. At 1.42 he has to pay $142,000. That’s his 140,000 plus $2,000 from his own pocket.

Just curious, what course is this homework for?